# PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto

Tags: linux, c, gcc, openssl, pam

I'm write a linux pam authentication module with c programming under ubuntu.My idea is when login input username and password that compare with web server saved username and password, if they are the same，then you can get into system,or you can't enter system.

Because web server is like https://xxxxxxxxx.com , so I write c code with openssl,
my c code(sensepam.c) is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>

#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int sendreq(pam_handle_t *pamh, int argc, const char *uname, const char *pwd)
{
    int i;
    pam_syslog(pamh, 5, "********into  sendreq******");

    /* first where are we going to send it? */
    int portno = 1234;
    char *host = "xxxxxxx.com";
    char *method = "GET";
    char *path = "/authModule/authenticate";
    char *header = "Host:xxxxxxx.com:1234";
    char body[1024];
    char* test_ok = "aaaaaaa";
    SSL *ssl = NULL;
    int OK_status = 0;
    X509 *server_cert;
    char* str = NULL;
    int err;
    char querystring[1024];
    //int argc = 6;
    int ret = 0;

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct in_addr ip;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total, message_size;
    const SSL_METHOD *client_method;
    char *message, response[4096];

    if (argc < 5) { puts("Parameters: <host> <port> <method> <path> [<data> [<headers>]]"); exit(0); }
    
    
    memset(querystring,0,1024);
    strcat(querystring,"username=");
    strcat(querystring,uname);
    strcat(querystring,"&password=");
    strcat(querystring,pwd);
    strcat(querystring,"&reamId=1024");
    printf("querystring is %s-%d", querystring, strlen(querystring));

    
    SSL_library_init();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    client_method = SSLv23_client_method( );
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(client_method);
    if (!ctx) {
        fprintf (stderr, "SSL_CTX_new failed:\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
        return 0;
    }
   
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    bcopy(server->h_addr, &(ip.s_addr), server->h_length);

    
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '\0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); 
    memcpy(&(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr),
            server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr,
                 sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (err < 0) { perror("can't connect to server port"); exit(1); }
 
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx); 
    if (!ssl) {
        fprintf (stderr, "SSL_new failed:\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd); 
    err = SSL_connect(ssl); 

    server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    printf("(6) server's certificate was received:\n\n");
    str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(server_cert), 0, 0);
    printf(" subject: %s\n", str);
    str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(server_cert), 0, 0);
    printf(" issuer: %s\n\n", str);

    X509_free(server_cert);


    /* How big is the message? */
    message_size=0;
    if(!strcmp(method,"GET"))
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n");        /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(path);                            /* path           */
        message_size+=strlen(header);                          /* headers        */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(querystring);                 /* query string   */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(header)+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen(method);                         /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(path);                         /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(header)+strlen("\r\n");
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen("Content-Length: %d\r\n")+10; /* content length */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(body);                     /* body           */
    }

    /* allocate space for the message */
    message=malloc(message_size);

    /* fill in the parameters */
    if(!strcmp(method,"GET"))
    {
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message,"%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(method)>0?method:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(path)>0?path:"/",                 /* path           */
                strlen(querystring)>0?"?":"",                      /* ?              */
                strlen(querystring)>0?querystring:"");                 /* query string   */
        else
            sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(method)>0?method:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(path)>0?path:"/");                /* path           */
        //for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
        {strcat(message,header);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */

        pam_syslog(pamh, 5, message);
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
            strlen(method)>0?method:"POST",                  /* method         */
            strlen(path)>0?path:"/");                    /* path           */
        //for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
        //    {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        //if(argc>5)
        //    sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Content-Length: %d\r\n",strlen(argv[5]));
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
        //if(argc>5)
        //    strcat(message,argv[5]);                           /* body           */
    }

    /* What are we going to send? */
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = SSL_write(ssl,message+sent,total-sent); 
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    shutdown (sockfd, 1); /* send EOF to server */

    pam_syslog(pamh, 5, response);
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (bytes > 0);
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);
   
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    close(sockfd);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
   

}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
        printf("Acct mgmt\n");
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
        int retval;

        const char* pUsername;
        const char* pPassword;
        char cmd[255];
        memset(cmd, 0, 255);

        retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");

        printf("Welcome %s\n", pUsername);

        if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
                return retval;
        }

        retval = pam_get_authtok(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &pPassword , NULL);

        pam_syslog(pamh, 5, "mypam.so login");
        pam_syslog(pamh, 5, pUsername);
        pam_syslog(pamh, 5, pPassword);


        if (!sendreq(pamh, 6, pUsername, pPassword)) {
                return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
        }

        pam_syslog(pamh, 5, "add user...");
        sprintf(cmd,"useradd -m %s",pUsername);
        system(cmd);

        return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *uname="aaaaa";
    char *pwd="123";
    sendreq(NULL, 6, uname, pwd);
}
```

my gdm-password is like below:

```
aaa@ubuntu:/etc/pam.d$  cat gdm-password 
auth sufficient sensepam.so
account sufficient sensepam.so

#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
@include common-account
# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any 
# lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible 
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_loginuid.so
# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
# pam_selinux.so changes the SELinux context of the used TTY and configures
# SELinux in order to transition to the user context with the next execve()
# call.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
@include common-password
```

my system infomation is like below:

```
aaa@ubuntu:~$  uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I  have installed openssl :

```
aaa@ubuntu:~$  openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
built on: Fri Jul  2 10:45:57 2021 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

I use below command to compile:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -fPIC -fno-stack-protector -c src/sensepam.c -lssl -lcrypto

sudo ld -x --shared -o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/sensepam.so  sensepam.o

rm sensepam.o
```

But when I try to login system,it can't work,so I view the log at /var/log/auth.log

```
Jul  5 15:50:54 ubuntu systemd-logind[644]: System is rebooting.
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: New seat seat0.
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:03 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: New session c1 of user gdm.
Jul  5 15:51:04 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:04 ubuntu su: (to aaa) root on none
Jul  5 15:51:04 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:04 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:04 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user aaa
Jul  5 15:51:06 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.71 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  5 15:51:12 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 15:51:12 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 15:51:12 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:14 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user aaa
Jul  5 15:51:15 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:15 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=uos001
Jul  5 15:51:19 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 15:51:19 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 15:51:19 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: New session 3 of user aaa.
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:22 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Jul  5 15:51:23 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[1830]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Jul  5 15:51:23 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[1830]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Jul  5 15:51:24 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:3 (system bus name :1.142 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  5 15:51:27 ubuntu gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jul  5 15:51:27 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul  5 15:51:27 ubuntu systemd-logind[646]: Removed session c1.
Jul  5 15:51:27 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.71, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul  5 15:51:29 ubuntu dbus-daemon[608]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jul  5 15:51:38 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user gdm
Jul  5 15:51:39 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:41 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:51:41 ubuntu sudo:      aaa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
Jul  5 15:51:41 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:51:41 ubuntu su: (to root) aaa on pts/0
Jul  5 15:51:41 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:57:28 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:57:32 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:57:32 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=aaa rhost=  user=aaa
Jul  5 15:57:35 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:57:37 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 15:57:37 ubuntu sudo:      aaa : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/aaa ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ld -x --shared -o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/sensepam.so /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so sensepam.o
Jul  5 15:57:37 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:57:37 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 15:57:40 ubuntu sudo:      aaa : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/aaa ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ld -x --shared -o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/sensepam.so /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so sensepam.o
Jul  5 15:57:40 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 15:57:40 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 16:07:15 ubuntu sudo:      aaa : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su -
Jul  5 16:07:15 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:07:15 ubuntu su: (to root) aaa on pts/1
Jul  5 16:07:15 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:04 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: New seat seat0.
Jul  5 16:09:04 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Jul  5 16:09:04 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jul  5 16:09:04 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Jul  5 16:09:04 ubuntu gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: New session c1 of user gdm.
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu su: (to aaa) root on none
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:05 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user aaa
Jul  5 16:09:07 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.71 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  5 16:09:17 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 16:09:17 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 16:09:17 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:09:20 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:09:20 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=uos001
Jul  5 16:09:24 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 16:09:24 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 16:09:24 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: New session 3 of user aaa.
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:09:27 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Jul  5 16:09:28 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[1842]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Jul  5 16:09:28 ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[1842]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Jul  5 16:09:29 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:3 (system bus name :1.147 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  5 16:09:30 ubuntu dbus-daemon[606]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jul  5 16:09:32 ubuntu gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jul  5 16:09:32 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul  5 16:09:32 ubuntu systemd-logind[649]: Removed session c1.
Jul  5 16:09:32 ubuntu polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.71, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul  5 16:17:01 ubuntu CRON[3961]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:17:01 ubuntu CRON[3961]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 16:30:01 ubuntu CRON[6263]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 16:30:01 ubuntu CRON[6263]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 16:42:09 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 16:42:09 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 16:42:09 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:42:14 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 16:42:14 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul  5 17:01:25 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 17:01:25 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 17:01:25 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:02:23 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:02:23 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul  5 17:17:01 ubuntu CRON[14250]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 17:17:01 ubuntu CRON[14250]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 17:22:02 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 17:22:02 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 17:22:02 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:22:05 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:22:05 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul  5 17:30:01 ubuntu CRON[16439]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 17:30:01 ubuntu CRON[16439]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  5 17:34:46 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
Jul  5 17:34:46 ubuntu gdm-password]: PAM adding faulty module: sensepam.so
Jul  5 17:34:46 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:34:50 ubuntu gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:34:50 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul  5 17:35:03 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:35:05 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul  5 17:35:05 ubuntu sudo:      aaa : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
Jul  5 17:35:05 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  5 17:35:05 ubuntu su: (to root) aaa on pts/0
Jul  5 17:35:05 ubuntu su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I think the error point  is :

```
PAM unable to dlopen(sensepam.so): /lib/security/sensepam.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
```

so Is there any way to solve this problem？Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When linking your shared library, you should add `-llib` parameters:

```
ld -x --shared -o sensepam.so sensepam.o -lcrypto -lssl
```

Then, after installing to `/lib/security`, find the missing dependencies using the following command:

```
ldd -r /lib/security/sensepam.so
```

The `ldd` command will print **all of the missing dependencies, undefined symbols** and the missing library files.

Now, copy the missing lib files, from the OpenSSL lib folder to the system library. The default system library path is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.